# android-sdk - unable to run the SDK manager

Tags: android, android-sdk

I'm trying to run the Android SDK manager tool using the following command inside the folder where android-sdk-tools are located.

```
./sdkmanager
```

It gives me the following error.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.SdkManagerCli
```

Can someone please help with this?

Comment: hello! 
have you solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another cleaner way to go about this is to follow the following steps:

- Go to `/path-to-android-sdk/`
- Delete the `Tools` directory
- Open Android Studio
- Open tools -> Sdk Manager
- Click on the `Sdk Tools` Tab
- Uncheck `Hide Obsolete Packages`
- Go into the Modal and check `Android Sdk Tools (Obsolete)`
- Click `Apply`
- Wait While it Downloads....
- When download is done,go back to `/path-to-android-sdk/`
- You should find your tools directory again
- Everything should work fine now.

**Note: What we simply did was delete and replace the old Tools which was corrupted or incompatible**

Answer (score 1):

I got this, so I went looking on a system where it worked. The command lives here:

```
unzip -t Android/Sdk/tools/lib/sdklib-26.0.0-dev.jar | grep sdkman
testing: com/android/sdklib/tool/sdkmanager/   OK
testing: com/android/sdklib/tool/sdkmanager/ListAction.class   OK
...etc
```

This zip doesn't exist on my bad machine. I have no idea why, and some of the .jar files in there complain about

```
bad extra-field entry:
  EF block length (0 bytes) invalid (< 4)
```

but I just copied what I needed from a working machine.